# scipy zpk2sos giving different result to Matlab zp2sos

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, signal-processing

Can anyone explain why this code gives different results in Python vs Matlab?

#### Matlab

```matlab
z = [0.97, 0.85, 0];
p = [0.97, 0.94, 0];
k = 0.2;

disp(zp2sos(z,p,k))
```

Output:

```sh
    0.2000   -0.1700         0    1.0000   -0.9400         0
    1.0000   -0.9700         0    1.0000   -0.9700         0
```

#### Python

```py
from scipy.signal import zpk2sos

z = [0.97, 0.85, 0]
p = [0.97, 0.94, 0]
k = 0.2

print(zpk2sos(z,p,k))
```

Output:

```sh
[[ 0.2     0.      0.      1.      0.      0.    ]
 [ 1.     -1.82    0.8245  1.     -1.91    0.9118]]
```

Comment: see https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/75321/difference-between-matlab-zp2sos-and-python-zpk2sos-functions

Comment: @eshirvana Thanks - that question seems different to mine? I have 6 different values whereas that problem is about the first 3 values being different.

Comment: There are many ways to convert ZPK data to SOS; the SOS representation is not unique.  Matlab and SciPy use different conventions in their conversions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using this code I found on github which defines a version of zpk2sos which gave me the same output as the MATLAB zp2sos. You might need to remove some old outdated packages from the code, but otherwise it worked fine for me.

https://gist.github.com/endolith/4525003/8ac88d203f874fd2b97498d50da818bbf5fac0f8